# Passing Multiple route params in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to pass multiple route params e.g. like below need to pass `id1` and `id2` to the `component B`

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/component/:id :id2',name: 'MyCompB', component:MyCompB }
])
export class MyCompA {
  onClick(){
    this._router.navigate( ['MyCompB', {id: "someId", id2: "another ID"}]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

OK realized a mistake .. it has to be `/:id/:id2`

Anyway didn't find this in any tutorial or other StackOverflow question.

```
@RouteConfig([{path: '/component/:id/:id2',name: 'MyCompB', component:MyCompB}])
export class MyCompA {
    onClick(){
        this._router.navigate( ['MyCompB', {id: "someId", id2: "another ID"}]);
    }
}
```

Comment: here is tutorial for same see In the routing section  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html

Comment: Lot has changed since answer was published.. Which version of angular2 you are working with ? in the ng2.0.0 release build:
`
const myRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'compBPath/:id1/:id2', component: MyCompB}
];
export const myRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(myRoutes);
`
 And in your NgModule
`
@NgModule({
  imports: [    myRouting  ],
  declarations: [    MyCompB  ],
})
export class MyModule {}

export class MyCompA {
    onClick(){
        this._router.navigate( ['compBPath', "val1", "val2"]);
    }
}
`

Comment: I also agree with @user3869623, as 
this._router.navigate( ['MyCompB', {id: "someId", id2: "another ID"}]);
denotes that 'id' and 'id2' are optional route params
while in the 
@RouteConfig([{path: '/component/:id/:id2',name: 'MyCompB', component:MyCompB}])

:id/:id2 are required route params although they are dynamic.

as, optional route params don't need to declare in the RouterConfig.

Answer (score 73):

As detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489793/2945345), mayur & user3869623's answer's are now relating to a deprecated router. You can now pass multiple parameters as follows:

To call router:

```
this.router.navigate(['/myUrlPath', "someId", "another ID"]);
```

In routes.ts:

```
{ path: 'myUrlpath/:id1/:id2', component: componentToGoTo},
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to know, it's also possible to add in between these ID variables some other term, which helps create a more user-friendly URL. Example: this.router.navigate(['/mypath', "firstId", "secondPath", "secondID"]) which allows for 'myPath/4/secondPath/5'

Comment: Is that also possible when using the routerlink in the template? I could not find a solution for that.

Comment: @julien-100000 - Yes it is, annotate as follows: [nsRouterLink]="['/myUrlPath',  'someId', 'another ID']"

Comment: @EamonBohan You saved my full day of investigation, you da real MVP, Thanks man!!!

Comment: I have this as my route path in app-routing.module.ts  { path: `:${id1}/test/:${id2}`, component: DummyComponentComponent } it does not load the component for me , also additionally i have a relative path in my index.html <base href="./"> , if i just leave the path with just one param then it works but if I extend it to having /export/:${id2} it stops working , any ideas ?

Answer (score 20):

Two Methods for Passing Multiple route params in Angular

Method-1

In app.module.ts

Set path as component2.

```
imports: [
 RouterModule.forRoot(
 [ {path: 'component2/:id1/:id2', component: MyComp2}])
]
```

Call router to naviagte to MyComp2 with multiple params id1 and id2.

```
export class MyComp1 {
onClick(){
    this._router.navigate( ['component2', "id1","id2"]);
 }
}
```

Method-2

In app.module.ts

Set path as component2.

```
imports: [
 RouterModule.forRoot(
 [ {path: 'component2', component: MyComp2}])
]
```

Call router to naviagte to MyComp2 with multiple params id1 and id2.

```
export class MyComp1 {
onClick(){
    this._router.navigate( ['component2', {id1: "id1 Value", id2: 
    "id2  Value"}]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
      new AsyncRoute({path: '/demo/:demoKey1/:demoKey2', loader: () => {
      return System.import('app/modules/demo/demo').then(m =>m.demoComponent);
       }, name: 'demoPage'}),
       export class demoComponent {
       onClick(){
            this._router.navigate( ['/demoPage', {demoKey1: "123", demoKey2: "234"}]);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the nested ids, for example this link:

```
this.router.navigate(['main', 'child', 1, 'grandchild', 2]);
```

> '/main/child/1/grandchild/2'

you can get the parent's ids with the route.parent, like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
let grandchild = this.route.snapshopt.paramMap.get('grandchild'); // 2
let child = this.route.snapshopt.parent.paramMap.get('child'); // 1
}
```