# Angular 2 router not working with multiple parameters passed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I created a sample Plunker, to pass in multiple parameter to the next page and it doesn't work. Here is the Plunker demonstration where crisis center routing doesn't work after click on items.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ngNSsKBzAuhaP0EjKVJX?p=preview

```
 onSelect(crisis: Crisis) {
    // Navigate with Absolute link
    //this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center', 1]); //this is working.
     this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center', { id: '1', id2:'2'}]); //this is not working
    }
```

//below is the routes:

```
//{ path: 'crisis-center/:id', component: CrisisDetailComponent } //-- this is working
  { path: 'crisis-center/:id /:id2', component: CrisisDetailComponent}, // this is not working

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .params
      .subscribe(params => {
        let id = +params['id'];
        let id2 = +params['id2']; //Unable to read id and id2 values
        this.service.getCrisis(id)
          .then(crisis => {
            if (crisis) {
              this.editName = crisis.name;
              this.crisis = crisis;
            } else { // id not found
              this.gotoCrises();
            }
          });
      });
  }
```

I have three layered navigation where it moves from crisis-center to crisis-details and then from crisi-details -> transactiondetail. So after I navigate to crisis details I want to pass crisisId and crisisdetailId to traverse back to detail and then crisis list.

I am trying to passing multiple parameter here.

Also, I want to hide the URL parameter from browser URL and show alias name, previously 'as' keyword used to work now it doesn't work.

Comment: try naming your second parameter something completely different, like "name" instead of "id2"

Comment: @JarodMoser it doesn't work I renamed id2 to name. I provided the plunker, if possible can you please try to edit that and see if it works. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry about the knee jerk reply, I've had some issues before naming params so close to eachother... @maxisam found the error for you

Comment: It looks like the accepted answer here was/is essentially "typo", so I will vote to put the question on hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a space in between at `crisis-center/:id /:id2`

here is the [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgehylornOgXhTaZX8Yn?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much, how can I hide the id's that are appearing on the browser urlI want to use alias name instead of actual url with Id's appearing on browser URL.

Earlies 'as' keyword and IsProd use to work now it not working. Can you please provide solution appreciate it.

Comment: sorry, I don't know but I think you should start a different question for this one, so you can get people to help you.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Router component (from **'@angular/router'**, not from **'@angular/router-deprecated'**), you pass multiple params as follows:

```
this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center', 1, 2]);
```

You were trying to do it:

```
this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center', { id: '1', id2:'2'}]); //this is not working
```

Because you've passed an object as a second argument, you were passing query parameters not router parameters. So, the URL for it is:

```
localhost:3000/crisis-center;id=1&id2=2
```

You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters